# TOC overflow when building git on AIX

Tags: git, makefile, 64-bit, aix, configure

I am getting the following linking error while trying to compile git in 64bit on AIX 6.1:

```
$ ./configure "CFLAGS=-maix64" "CXXFLAGS=-maix64" "LDFLAGS=-maix64" && /usr/opt/freeware/bin/make

<compilation/linking output>

ld: 0711-781 ERROR: TOC overflow. TOC size: 90720       Maximum size: 65536
collect2: error: ld returned 12 exit status
make: *** [git] Error 1
```

Comment: A note: it is not really anyone's fault, it's a limitation of the CPU's instruction-set. Let's mention the fact that while -bbigtoc solves it, the linker has to modify the code in some objects modules: in those that were compiled with the assumption that the toc will be 'small'. At compilation option -qpic=large (xlC) or -fPIC/-fPIE (gcc) can be used to force assuming big toc. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/overview-toc-aix/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to specify the `-bbigtoc` linker option to avoid this problem according to [ld: 0711-781 ERROR: TOC overflow](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21175442)

The correct compilation line is :

```
$ ./configure "CFLAGS=-maix64" "CXXFLAGS=-maix64" "LDFLAGS=-maix64 -Wl,-bbigtoc" && /usr/opt/freeware/bin/make
```

Other solutions include:

- Break up large segments of code into smaller compilation units
- Reduce the number of variables in the compilation unit